# Animation delays generation with LESS

Tags: css, animation, less

I am trying to generate animation delays with LESS. The final result should be similar to:

```
[data-animation-delay="1"] {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}
[data-animation-delay="2"] {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

My code looks like:

```
@animation-delays: 10;
@animation-delay-step: .5; // delay in seconds

.animation-delays-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    [data-animation-step="@{i}"] {
        @animation-delay = @animation-delay-step * @{i};
        animation-delay: @animation-delay~"s";
    }
    .animation-delays-loop(@i - 1);
}
.animation-delays-loop (@animation-delays);
```

However, it doesn't work. The problem seems to be in `animation-delay: @animation-delay~"s";`. Any ideas how to correct it?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying by `1s`?

Comment: @chazsolo, thanks I found the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I ended up with doing this:

```
@animation-delays: 10;
@animation-delay-step: .5; // delay in seconds

.animation-delays-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
    [data-animation-step="@{i}"] {
        @animation-delay: @i * @animation-delay-step;
        animation-delay: ~"@{animation-delay}s";
    }
    .animation-delays-loop(@i - 1);
}
.animation-delays-loop (@animation-delays);
```

worked like a charm.